# Variant of interval scheduling with varying task durations

Tags: algorithms, optimization, greedy-algorithms, scheduling, intervals

I am probably just missing the correct term for my problem to find the solution but here it goes:

I have a set of tasks with a given duration and an interval for each task in which it has to be completed. I now need to find start times for the tasks, so that

1. each tasks is completed within its interval
2. no task overlaps with another task

Sketch:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Above all, what is your question? Also, even though this question looks like not complicated, can you add a url or reference to in the question? That will help people to answer your question faster and better.

Comment: I have added a different image that maybe explains the problem better. I need to shift the colored bars in positions so that no colored bar overlaps with another AND each colored bar is within its intrerval (black bars).

Comment: Can you tell us whether this is an open problem, tricky problem or an entry-level problem or just a complete new problem created by you? Context is just too important. That is why I am going to ask it again, can you add a url or reference? By the way, your image is really wonderful.

Comment: This seems an NP-complete problem by a reduction from 3-Partition, as suggested by [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0206029), but it does not give a detailed proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deterministic version of your problem (i.e. to determine whether there is a valid arrangement) is strongly NP-complete by a reduction from [3-Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem), as suggested in [1].

Given an instance $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{3m}$ of 3-Partition, let the duration in your problem be $[0, mB+m]$ where $B=\sum_{i=1}^{3m} x_i/m$. For each element $x_i$, there is a task with duration $x_i$. The intervals for these tasks are all $[0, mB+m]$. In addition, there are additionally $m$ tasks with duration $1$, and their intervals are respectively $[B, B+1], [2B+1, 2B+2],\ldots,[mB+m-1,mB+m]$. Note the positions of these additional tasks are fixed.

Since we can assume $B/4<x_i<B/2$ for all $i$ in 3-Partition, we can see there is a valid partition if and only if there is a valid arrangement in your problem.

---

[1] Garey, M. R., & Johnson, D. S. (1977). Two-processor scheduling with start-times and deadlines. *SIAM Journal on Computing*, 6(3), 416-426.